# check if a date falls in the next 24 hours with c #

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

it is possible with C # test whether the DateTime " 01/29/2016 16:22:00 " is included in the next 24 hours? I have a date that is " 01/28/2016 15:30 " ( DateTime.Now ) and I 'd like to know if it is within the range going forward 24 hours. I hope I explained .

Comment: You want to know if `DateTime.Now` is within the next 24 hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AddHours`:

```
var myDateTime = ...
var now = DateTime.Now;

if (myDateTime <= now.AddHours(24)
    && myDateTime >= now.AddHours(-24))
{

}
```

Also keep in mind that `DateTime` is immutable and they cannot be modified after creation. That is why `AddHours` returns a new instance.

**Update:**
After seeing M.kazem's answer I have though that you can also use that:

```
Math.Abs(myDateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalHours) <= 24
```

Comment: for my case your answere works! thanks

Comment: @Mr.Developer Glad to help. Also, updated my answer. You can use second one also.

Comment: The update works for me perfectly :) thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
(yourDatetime - DateTime.Now) <= TimeSpan.FromHours(24)
```

Comment: And if your time was 5 years ago?

Comment: It will not work if the `yourDatetime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-26)`; You can use `Math.Abs`.